# sbt -jvm-debug port ignored on Windows 10

Tags: playframework, sbt

I want to run sbt in debug mode on Windows 10 with command:

```
sbt -jvm-debug 5005 run
```

But sbt changes listening port to 54430 with following message in log:

> Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 54430

How to fix port on sbt with Windows 10?

Comment: How/where do you launch the sbt command? This looks surprising

Comment: Also, is it always port 54430 or rather a random port each time?

Comment: I run on Window Power Shell or on CMD. It rather a random port each time recompile. I have this problem on Window 10 only and others pc like Macbook it is no problem.

Comment: Did you try with the regular Java options `-J-Xdebug -J-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005` instead? It's more a workaround than a solution though..

Comment: Merci. J'ai essayé avec set SBT_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005
sbt run. Ca marche :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **git bash** this command will work on Windows 10:

```
sbt -jvm-debug 5005 run
```

But if you are using **PowerShell** or **CMD** you are going to need to change the **"-jvm-debug"** or just ignore the command and add another one **"address"**:

```
sbt -jvm-debug 5005 run address=5005
```